# What is Multi-bump solutions for a PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, reference-works

In the papers:

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0294144905000041;
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123609000597;
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022039699936501,

The authors are studying solutions for a PDE, called "Multi-bump", but, isn't clear for me what does it mean.

Thanks in advance